# Adding a shape to the end of a horizontal bar chart in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

Executives at my organization only accept data reported like this:
[image]

Unfortunately, I have been unable to get excel to automatically place the red triangles in the appropriate location. The only way I have found to accomplish this is to plot the red bar (2016 baseline), position the triangles appropriately, and then delete the bar. This is fine and dandy until we have to rescale the graphs, add and remove data, etc. because they need to be manually moved every time. I there a way to programmatically do this in the VBE? I have never written macros for Excel, I tend to steer toward R, SQL, or Tableau for my data vis needs but this is the only way that the report will be accepted.

Comment: There are a few ways to do this. You can place the triangles with a scatterplot, and choose the triangle shape from the "marker options", but then you have to place the vertically correctly, which takes some formula tricks.

Comment: It's also possible to do them with horizontal bars as well. You can use an image fill to create the triangle then. Just make sure you use a transparent image or you'll get an ugly box around it. And the width of the horizontal bar has to be right or the triangle will stretch.

Comment: None of this involves macros, by the way.

Comment: If you let me know which general approach you are interested in, I could post an answer with more details.